# Why did Starlord's body start to disintegrate while holding an infinity stone?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Given Starlord is of [celestial](http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials) origin, why did he start to disintegrate when holding an infinity stone in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 1*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter's half human as well as Celestial.

Note that the Collector's servant girl essentially exploded almost immediately on grabbing the Power stone and Peter lasted a fair bit longer, long enough for the others to assist in a kind of power-sharing group (much like the Collector described to them).

Comment: This is also connected to/foreshadowed by the reason he was able to stay alive in Space for so long as well, earlier in the movie.